# Arrays with string keys or nested quotes into a lambda function in php

Tags: php, arrays, lambda, quotes

I want to create a lambda function, i'm doing this:

```
create_function('$range',  'return " ( ABS(a.price) > format_money($range["min"] AND ABS(a.price) <  format_money($range["max"]) ) OR a.price is null " ');
```

But the $range["min"] part breaks my attempt ... there's a problem with nested quotes and i don't know how to solve it , i don't even know if it is possible to do this or php is not that powerful, any light?

Comment: You can escape your `"` using `\"`

Comment: May be this helpful to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1909002/what-use-is-lambda-in-php

Answer (score 2):

Using escaped single quotes and a `;` got it to parse, don't know about the execution.

```
create_function('$range',  'return \' ( ABS(a.price) > format_money($range["min"] AND ABS(a.price) <  format_money($range["max"]) ) OR a.price is null \'; ');
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call variables inside of single quotes.

```
create_function('$range',  'return " ( ABS(a.price) > format_money('.$range["min"].' AND ABS(a.price) <  format_money('.$range["max"].') ) OR a.price is null " ');
```

Comment: but what i need is to pass $range["min"] as a string , not the value!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this done by concatenating your values to the string like this:

```
create_function('$range',  'return " ( ABS(a.price) > format_money(" . $range["min"] . " AND ABS(a.price) <  format_money(" . $range["max"] . ") ) OR a.price is null "; ');
```

The output of that function was:

```
string(92) " ( ABS(a.price) > format_money(10 AND ABS(a.price) <  format_money(20) ) OR a.price is null "
```

Answer (score 0):

Forget it, it was wrongly composed, the correct way is:

```
create_function('$range',  'return " ( ABS(a.price) > ".format_money($range[\'min\'])." AND ABS(a.price) < ".format_money($range[\'max\'])." ) OR a.price is null "; ');
```

now it works!