# I need to change the pagination of this Wordpress slideshow plugin to display as numbers instead of images

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

I have a Wordpress plugin (called Slideshow, found [here](http://wordpress.org/plugins/slideshow-jquery-image-gallery/)) that has pagination above the slides that displays as bullets in a ul ([link to slideshow page](http://www.hagopvanesian.com/syrians-internally-displaced-2/)).

What I need is for it to display as numbers in the following format: "Picture 1 of 15". I am new to javascript and am having a very hard time getting it to do this. I was able to identify (at least I think I was) the sections of code that need to be altered for this.

The PHP ([link to file](http://www.hagopvanesian.com/wp-content/plugins/slideshow-jquery-image-gallery/slideshow.php)):

```
<div class="slideshow_container slideshow_container_<?php echo     htmlspecialchars($styleName); ?>" style="<?php echo (isset($settings['preserveSlideshowDimensions']) && $settings['preserveSlideshowDimensions'] == 'false' && isset($settings['height']) && $settings['height'] > 0) ? 'height: ' . $settings['height'] . 'px;' : ''; ?> <?php echo (isset($settings['maxWidth']) && $settings['maxWidth'] > 0) ? 'max-width: ' . $settings['maxWidth'] . 'px;' : ''; ?>" data-session-id="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($sessionID); ?>" data-style-name="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($styleName); ?>" data-style-version="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($styleVersion); ?>">

<?php if(isset($settings['showLoadingIcon']) && $settings['showLoadingIcon'] === 'true'): ?>
    <div class="slideshow_loading_icon"></div>
<?php endif; ?>

<div class="slideshow_content" style="display: none;">

    <?php

    if(is_array($views) && count($views) > 0)
    {
        foreach($views as $view)
        {
            echo $view->toFrontEndHTML();
        }
    }

    ?>

</div>

<div class="slideshow_controlPanel slideshow_transparent" style="display: none;"><ul><li class="slideshow_togglePlay" data-play-text="<?php _e('Play', 'slideshow-plugin'); ?>" data-pause-text="<?php _e('Pause', 'slideshow-plugin'); ?>"></li></ul></div>

<div class="slideshow_button slideshow_previous slideshow_transparent" role="button" data-previous-text="<?php _e('Previous', 'slideshow-plugin'); ?>" style="display: none;"></div>
<div class="slideshow_button slideshow_next slideshow_transparent" role="button" data-next-text="<?php _e('Next', 'slideshow-plugin'); ?>" style="display: none;"></div>

<div class="slideshow_pagination" style="display: none;" data-go-to-text="<?php _e('Go to slide', 'slideshow-plugin'); ?>"><div class="slideshow_pagination_center"></div></div>

<!-- WordPress Slideshow Version <?php echo SlideshowPluginMain::$version; ?> -->

<?php if(is_array($log) && count($log) > 0): ?>
<!-- Error log
<?php foreach($log as $logMessage): ?>
    - <?php echo htmlspecialchars($logMessage); ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
-->
<?php endif; ?>
```

The JS ([link to file](http://www.hagopvanesian.com/wp-content/plugins/slideshow-jquery-image-gallery/js/min/all.frontend.min.js)):

```
prototype.activatePagination = function () {
    if (this.settings.showPagination) {
        this.$pagination.find(".slideshow_pagination_center").html("<ul></ul>");
        var i = this.$pagination.find("ul");
        i.html(""), this.$views.each(t.proxy(function (t) {
            var s = "",
                e = parseInt(t, 10) + 1,
                n = this.$pagination.data("goToText");
            ("string" != typeof n || n.length <= 0) && (n = this.$pagination.attr("data-go-to-text")), t == this.currentViewID && (s = "slideshow_currentView"), i.append('<li class="slideshow_transparent ' + s + '" data-view-id="' + t + '" role="button" title="' + n + " " + e + '"><span class="assistive-text hide-text">' + n + " " + e + "</span></li>")
        }, this)), this.$pagination.find("li").attr("tabindex", "0").click(t.proxy(function (i) {
            var s, e = t(i.currentTarget);
            this.currentlyAnimating || (s = e.data("viewId"), isNaN(parseInt(s, 10)) && (s = e.attr("data-view-id"), isNaN(parseInt(s, 10))) || (this.pauseAllVideos(), this.playState === this.PlayStates.PLAYING && (this.pause(this.PlayStates.TEMPORARILY_PAUSED), this.play()), this.animateTo(parseInt(s, 10), 0)))
        }, this)), this.bindSubmitListener(this.$pagination.find("li")), this.$container.bind("slideshowAnimationStart", t.proxy(function () {
            var i = this.$pagination.find("li");
            i.each(t.proxy(function (i, s) {
                t(s).removeClass("slideshow_currentView")
            }, this)), t(i[this.currentViewID]).addClass("slideshow_currentView")
        }, this)), this.settings.hidePagination ? (this.$container.mouseenter(t.proxy(function () {
            this.$pagination.stop(!0, !0).fadeIn(100)
        }, this)), this.$container.mouseleave(t.proxy(function () {
            this.$pagination.stop(!0, !0).fadeOut(500)
        }, this))) : this.$pagination.show()
    }
}, i.Slideshow.prototype.activatePauseOnHover = function () {
    this.settings.pauseOnHover && (this.$container.mouseenter(t.proxy(function () {
        clearTimeout(this.pauseOnHoverTimer), this.playState !== this.PlayStates.PAUSED && (this.pauseOnHoverTimer = setTimeout(t.proxy(function () {
            this.pause(this.PlayStates.TEMPORARILY_PAUSED)
        }, this), 500))
    }, this)), this.$container.mouseleave(t.proxy(function () {
        clearTimeout(this.pauseOnHoverTimer), this.playState !== this.PlayStates.PAUSED && this.interval === !1 && this.play()
    }, this)))
}
}();
slideshow_jquery_image_gallery_backend_script_scriptsloadedFlag = !0;
```

I hope this is sufficient information. There is also a file called all.backend.min.js that I'm not sure is needed, but here is a [link](http://www.hagopvanesian.com/wp-content/plugins/slideshow-jquery-image-gallery/js/min/all.backend.min.js) to it just in case.

Also if anyone has an alternate plugin they can suggest that already does something similar, that will suffice. I can edit the CSS to display the way I want, but I am not good enough with Javascript to edit an existing plugin.

Comment: when I try to go to the links you posted, it went to a 404. Maybe some access control issue?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I had to find a workaround because I ran out of time. It wont let me delete the question because there is an open bounty on it.

Answer (score 4):

We can add CSS and jQuery to hide and modify the output of the slider. It's pure extra code without touching the original. Can be used on `functions.php` or better yet on a [custom plugin](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/73031/where-to-put-my-code-plugin-or-functions-php).

With CSS we hide things:

```
# Required: PHP 5.3
# See Lambda functions: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1909002/1287812
add_action( 'wp_head', function() {
    ?>
    <style>
    .slideshow_container_style-light .slideshow_pagination ul li {
        background: none !important; /* was the bullet img */
    }
    span.assistive-text.hide-text { /* unhide text */
        display: block !important;
        font:15px arial,sans-serif;
        position: initial !important;
        text-shadow: #000 1px 1px 1px;
        color:#fff;
    }
    </style>
    <?php
});
```

And with jQuery we modify:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', function(){ wp_enqueue_script('jquery'); } );

add_action( 'wp_footer', function() {
    ?>
    <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {  
        function startUp() {
            $("span.assistive-text.hide-text").each(function() {
                var text = $(this).text();
                text = text.replace("Go to slide", "");
                $(this).text(text);
            });
        }
        /* Wait slideshow start to fire the replace function */
        var timeoutID = window.setTimeout( startUp, 1500 ); 
    });
    </script>
    <?php
});
```

The result is the removal of the bullets and display of numbers. To create a navigation `Picture 1 of 15` further jQuery is needed, but nothing that a [Stack Overflow search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&pagesize=50&q=%5bjquery%5d%20%2beach%20%2breplace%20is%3aanswer) wouldn't help to answer.

[image]

Comment: Nice solution (+1) - I see that you've been blogging for quite a while, according to your archives  ;-)

Comment: Holy macro! Good catch :)